# How to remove or hide button on Microsoft Office (2007) ribbon

Tags: microsoft-excel, gui, microsoft-office-2007, ribbon, file-filter

I am using Microsoft Excel 2007.  Can I permanently remove or hide the “Filter” button? – I don't want to use that button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done via the UI in Excel 2007.  But Excel 2010 and later you can do this by right clicking the ribbon and clicking "Customize Ribbon"

For example, [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-ribbon-in-Office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31) is how it is done in Excel 2016

There are more advanced ways of customizing the ribbon in Excel 2007, but it is very involved and will require some coding, as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)